# How to keep picturebox in the form while moving it?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I'm trying to make a single game, but I got a little problem here...
I'm moving a picturebox with the arrow keys, to avoid other pictureboxes... The problem is, that my picturebox moves out of the form when I press the left key too many times... I succeeded in solving this problem with the right side(by blocking the picturebox with an another), but the left side version still doesn't works, and I don't know why...

Here is the code:

```
if (pictureBox7.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox1.Bounds))
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Escape: Application.Exit(); break;
                case Keys.P: timerkunai1.Enabled = false;
                    timerkunai2.Enabled = false; timerkunai3.Enabled = false;
                    timerkunai4.Enabled = false; timerninja.Enabled = false;
                    timerlife.Enabled = false;
                    button3.Show(); break;
                case Keys.Right: i = 6; dx = 25; press = true; break;            
            }
        if (pictureBox8.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox1.Bounds))
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Escape: Application.Exit(); break;
                case Keys.P: timerkunai1.Enabled = false;
                    timerkunai2.Enabled = false; timerkunai3.Enabled = false;
                    timerkunai4.Enabled = false; timerninja.Enabled = false;
                    timerlife.Enabled = false;
                    button3.Show(); break;
                case Keys.Left: i = 0; dx = -25; press = true; break;
            }
        else
            switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Escape: Application.Exit(); break;
            case Keys.P: timerkunai1.Enabled = false;
                timerkunai2.Enabled = false; timerkunai3.Enabled = false;
                timerkunai4.Enabled = false; timerninja.Enabled = false;
                timerlife.Enabled = false;
                button3.Show(); break;
            case Keys.Left: i = 0; dx = -25; press = true; break;
            case Keys.Right: i = 6; dx = 25; press = true; break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need code to check if the picturebox's bounds are outside of the form.  If the picturebox movement will cause it to be outside the bounds then prevent the motion.
Something like this pseudocode:
`if (pictureBoxZ + dx < 0 || pictureBoxZ + dx > pictureBoxZ.Parent.Width) { //Deny Motion }`

Answer (score 0):

Is your dx variable an offset to the new Location of the PictureBox?
Then limit the Location.x to 0:

```
 if (pictureBox1.Location.x + dx > 0)
     pictureBox1.Location += dx;
```

If you want to limit to left and right size, to the width of the Form use this code:

```
if ((pictureBox1.Location.x + dx > 0) && (pictureBox1.Location.x + dx < this.Size.Width - pictureBox1.Size.Width))
     pictureBox1.Location += dx;
```